# default arguments removed in gtk3?

Tags: pygtk, pyside, gtk3

I try to port my pygtk code to gtk3. I get this error:

```
TypeError: pack_start() takes exactly 5 argument(s) (2 given)
```

It seams that the default arguments have been removed.

Does gtk3 (accessed from python) not support default arguments?

Since the app is not big, I ask myself if I should port to gtk3 or pyside ...

Removing the default arguments looks like a pointless "job creation programm" for programmers...

I could not find a good porting guide (pygtk to python-gtk3). Only this:

- http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Features/GTK3/Porting#HBox.2C_VBox.2C_pack_start_and_pack_end

Code like this is ugly:

```
box.pack_start(widget, True, True, 0)
```

I know how to search+replace .... but I don't want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two options that I can suggest. One is you use the [pygtkcompat compability module](https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting). This is probably not a good long term solution though.

The other option is to patch just the `pack_start` method in the same way the compatbility module does. Something like this:

```
orig_pack_start = Gtk.Box.pack_start
def pack_start(self, child, expand=True, fill=True, padding=0):
    orig_pack_start(self, child, expand, fill, padding)
Gtk.Box.pack_start = pack_start
```

This assumes you only want to patch one or two methods. More than that and it's probably better to stick with the compatibility module.